# How to print the sum of the first and last element, second and second last and so on.., of an array after you input the elements using pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, sum

I got to this point which does what i intended it to but i need to incorporate pointers, which is what i need help with.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int a[50],n,i,j;
   {
   cout<<"Input number of elements: "<<endl;
   cin>>n;
}
cout<<"Input elements: ";
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    cin>>a[i];
cout<<"Array is:"<<endl;
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    cout<<a[i]<<endl;

   for(i=0,j=n-1;i<j;i++,j--)
  {
  a[i]=a[i]+a[j];
  }
  for(i=0;i<n/2;i++)

   cout<<a[i]<<",";
    return 0;
}
```

This prints:
Example 1,2,3,4,5,6 -----> 7  7  7

Comment: what did you try? What is your specific question?

Comment: So basically after the array is set and printed out i need another array printed out that has the first element as a sum of the first and last element, second element would be a sum of the second and second last element of the original array and so on. This has to be done with pointers somehow but i dont know how to use pointers.

Comment: no you do not need an additional array. If you only want to print the sums you need not store them in an array. Please include a [mcve] of your code in the question

Comment: note that you modified the question so much that now my answer does not make sense any more, because it refers to code that is not in your question anymore. You should not change your question substantially after you received answers. Usually I would roll back such an edit, but not this time. Its really not a big deal, but consider that you basically wasted the effort that I put into your question

Answer (score 0):

Not going to give you the whole code....

Consider the loop that prints the array backwards:

```
for(i=(10-1); i>=0; i--)
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";
```

Try to write the same loop in a different way:

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
        cout<<a[ ?? ]<<" ";
```

Because then it is almost the same as the loop that prints the array in forward order:

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    cout<<a[i]<<endl;
```

And you can combine them into one. And the only thing that is left is to stop after iterating half of the array:

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
        cout << "sum = " << a[i] + a[ ?? ] << "\n";
```

This assumes the user always enters 10 numbers. If that is not the case you need to count how many numbers the user entered. This would be easier when you use a `std::vector` for the dynamically sized array. If fixed size of `10` is fine, the above should be all you need, you just need to find the right thing to replace the `??` with.